Why does the catalogue in my ECommerce website keep bouncing to top of page when new items are loaded?
I've recently been doing work on my website and noticed that when I go to the product catalogue and scroll down enough to load new products the scroll bar then bounces back to the top of the page. The page has an endless scroll. Is there anyway that I can fix this? It's a Shopify run website, and I've been attempting to find a fix for the last couple weeks to no avail. Here is the page with an example of what happens: Catalogue Example. I'm assuming it has something to do with the top of the page being pinned as even when first loading the page it will bounce you to the top of the catalogue.
I tried disabling a setting that was labeled as "auto-scroll when loading items" but it didn't change anything on the page. I've also checked various sources and have not been able to find a solution.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.
